# When using `dplyr::summarise()` with the `across()` function can I mix the list and formula syntax

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use `dplyr::summarise()` with the `dplyr::across()` function to produce a table that has the number of non-missing values, the mean and standard deviation for a couple variables.  I can get the information on the missing values and the mean using the purrr modeling syntax but I can't figure out how to get the summaries into a single table without using multiple summarise calls and then `bind_cols()`

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), ~sum(!is.na(.))))

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Is there a way to combine the list syntax:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), list(mean = mean, sd = sd)))
```

with the `purrr` function syntax shown above to get the number of not missing values, the mean and standard deviation all at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To apply multiple functions in the same `across` statement you can use the `list` syntax as :

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), list(sum = ~sum(!is.na(.)), 
                                              mean = mean, sd = sd)))
```